# How can I stop a sub-project from getting built?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I have a large-ish Qt project that has multiple subprojects.

One of the sub-projects is intentionally unbuildable, and I don't want QtCreator to try to build it. I still want all its source files visible in the project tree, however.

How can I prevent a project from getting built?

Is there a *TEMPLATE = NONE* or *TARGET = PLZ_DONT_BUILD*?

Answer (score 1):

The hacky solution I've come up with is wrapping all my source files with:

```
DisableBuild {
    SOURCES = DummyMain.cpp
} else {

    SOURCES = main.cpp \ 
              ...many other files...


} #...at the bottom of the .pro file.
```

DummyMain.cpp just contains an empty int main() function, so the compiler doesn't complain about empty entry points.

If there is a better solution, I'd like to hear it!

Comment: It it is a truly subproject, then you could apply the same technique to the top level .pro file where you have the 'SUBDIRS +=' command.

Comment: @jwernerny I still want all its source files visible in the project tree, and if I conditionally remove it from SUBDIRS it'd hide the files - and entire subproject - from the project view.